# Fatal Error when trying to uninstall Zoom

Tags: 20.04, zoom-meeting

I was trying to install the new version of Zoom without success. Attempting to uninstall Zoom to reinstall it after, I am receiving an unrecoverable fatal error message on my terminal.

```
yd@yd-Inspiron-5575:~$ sudo apt remove zoom
[sudo] password for yd:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libegl1-mesa libxcb-xtest0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  zoom
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
After this operation, 204 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 loading files list file for package 'humanity-icon-theme': cannot read /var/lib/dpkg/info/humanity-icon-theme.list (Input/output error)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
yd@yd-Inspiron-5575:~$
```

Comment: When running sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade, I do receive the same error message

Comment: For refrence: I ran the following commands: sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/humanity-icon-theme.list  , then, sudo apt install --reinstall humanity-icon-theme    it seems to be a successful fix